# Addition of HOCl to ethyne

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

What is the product formed in addition of HOCl to ethyne? Is it dichloroacetaldehyde, or perhaps the enol form of dichloroacetaldehyde could react further with HOCl to form chloral hydrate / chloral?

[image]

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/134154/reaction-of-acetylene-with-hypochlorous-acid

Comment: All of it is rather dubious, as aldehydes oxidise very easily.